# Record with Maximum count of an attribute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a employeebook table having the employee id and book id column(among others).

```
Emp_id|Book_id|.......
```

There is another table HistoryBooks:

```
Book_id|description|.....
```

Please note that **not all books an employee has would necessarily be history books**.

I need to find out the 10 employees having maximum number of history books - the employee id and the number of history books they possess.

I am using SQL Server 2008.
Help is appreciated

Comment: select top 10 emp_id, count(book_id) from employeebook group by emp_id

Comment: Please have a look at the requirement - its not a simple Max.

Comment: select top 10 emp_id, count(b.book_id) from employeebook e join historyBooks b on e.book_id = b.book_id group by emp_id

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 10 emp_id,count(distinct book_id)
from employeebook 
where isnull(book_id,0)<>0
group by emp_id
```

**Update Query**

```
select top 10 e.emp_id,count(distinct b.book_id)
from employeebook e
inner join HistoryBooks b on e.book_id=b.book_id
group by emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use **Group By** for this

```
select top 10 emp_id, count(book_id) as NoOfBookID from EmployeeBook group by emp_id
```